# Sum of reciprocals in finite fields

Tags: co.combinatorics, finite-groups, finite-fields

Let $p$ be an odd prime number which large enough. I am interested in the study of the sums of reciprocals in the field $\mathbb{F}_p$.
In particular, I have the following question:
 which primes $p$ do satisfy
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{j\equiv
1\pmod{5}}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}j^{-1}\not\equiv\sum_{j\equiv
3\pmod{5}}^{\frac{p-1}{2}}j^{-1}\pmod{p}\quad ?
\end{equation*}
Thanks for any comments or any helpful references.

Comment: Have you done any numerical experiments?

Comment: According to my calculations, the equality fails e.g. for $p=17$ and $p=1867$.

Comment: This is true for almost all primes up to $10^{14}$ using pariGP.

Comment: Are there any other exclusions? Can you list them, if so?

Comment: A reasonable guess might be that the residues of the the left and right hand sides modulo $p$ act like independent, uniformly-distributed random variables. If so, we should expect that there are infinitely many $p$ for which the two sides are congruent, and that the number of $p\leq x$ for which there is congruence grows like $\log\log x$. But questions like this are hard, and I expect it will be difficult to prove that there are infinitely many $p$ for which congruence holds, or even that there are infinitely many $p$ for which congruence does not hold.

Comment: Thanks @JulianRosen for the comment. Note that this is related to the behavior of the map $\mathbb{F}_{p}^{\times}\rightarrow\mathbb{F}_{p}^{\times}$ which send an element to its inverse, and I think that there is no references which provide any description of these maps while $p$ is varying !?